# Not instantiable An internal server error occurred after edit config/main.php

Tags: php, yii2

I have a problem with my yii2-advanced after editing `config/main.php`.

I have added

```
'formatter' => [
    'class' => 'yii\i18n\formatter',
    'thousandSeparator' => '.',
    'decimalSeparator' => ',',
],
```

In `main/config.php`, it works in local but when I deploy it to production it is an error.

Comment: Are the PHP versions the same? [Traling comma](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/list-syntax-trailing-commas) in arrays is available since PHP 7.2

Comment: What do you mean by "it is an error"? The array you've shared isn't executed in any way, so it cannot throw an error on its own

Answer (score 0):

Write class name with capital letter

```
'formatter' => [
 'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
'thousandSeparator' => '.',
'decimalSeparator' => ',',
],
```